# Can a werewolf kill himself?

Tags: werewolf

I was moderator in a game and one of the nights, one of the wolves chose himself to die.

I was a little disconcerted, but later he explained that it was because he trusted that the witch would save him and after that, the villagers would trust him.

It is a solid but risky strategy. But ... is it a valid strategy? Can a wolf (if the majority agrees) be one of the victims of the attack?

Comment: How would picking yourself trick the villagers into trusting you?

Comment: Villagers no, but if the witch saves you, probably thinks that you are not a wolf, and you gain an ally.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Werewolf is the name of a family of games, not a specific game. So the answer will vary depending on the rules of the specific game. I think the more common answer would be "No, because they have to pick a 'villager', and the werewolves aren't 'villagers'."

e.g.,:

https://www.playwerewolf.co/rules

But other rulesets vary in their phrasing, with some even explicitly allowing the selection of a werewolf.

Comment: That is a strange statement. In my game (the French version) it states that they pick "a victim".

Comment: And in this website, which is indicated as a reference from the editor of the game I have, the rules plainly state that a group of werewolves can vote against another one : http://www.loups-garous.com

Comment: There are multiple printed versions of Werewolf.  The one being sold on playwerewolf.co is different from Ultimate Werewolf and from The Werewolves of Miller Hollow

Comment: Of course, when playing a particular version, use the rules that come with that version. Since the OP didn't specify, I just referenced the generic rules.

Comment: @L.ScottJohnson I agree that the question would be better if it specified a version of werewolf.  However, those are not "generic" rules you reference, but rather the rules from a specific version of werewolf.  To draw a general conclusion about all werewolf versions from a piece of nuance in the rules from a specific version is misleading.

Comment: OK. Edited to reflect the comments.

Answer (score 2):

The question really depends on which version you are playing.

---

### The Werewolves of Miller's Hollow

The werewolves are explicitly allowed to kill a werewolf:

> If a werewolf is selected as a victim by the other werewolves, hard luck, he dies!

---

### Stellar Factory Werewolf (playwerewolf.co)

The werewolves cannot kill a werewolf:

> The moderator says "Werewolves, pick someone to kill." The werewolves silently agree on one villager.

---

### Ultimate Werewolf

The werewolves can pick a werewolf as the rules do not specify it must be a villager:

> Each night, the Werewolves choose a player to eliminate

Answer (score -1):

Short answer: **No**, a player (whether he is wolf or villager) **cannot kill himself**

The rule clearly states that a player who is a lover must not cast a vote (even to mislead others) against his partner. This  rule can only make sense if we consider that a player **cannot vote against himself** either.

However, the other players have indeed the right to vote against one of their fellow-villager/wolf. This is allowed during the day, and I believe can also be done during the night for strategic reasons. For instance a group of wolves could attack another one that they suspect to be the white wolf (available in one extension).

So, the strategy you mentioned could work, but it requires at least 3 wolves in play (if we consider that all must place a vote, two wolves would lead to a draw when one decides to vote against his peer).

**---- EDIT ----**

I am basing this explanation on the game "Les loups-garous de Thiercelieux"  (English version is "The Werewolves of Millers Hollow"). This is as far as I know the original werewolves game using the older "Mafia" concept.

The rules in French version of this game do allow werewolves voting against each other, and this possibility is clearly stated in this official website: http://www.loups-garous.com

Comment: I'm quite curious to know where it's written you can't vote for yourself as a werewolf. A witch can kill herself/save herself and that's "basically" the same kind of power.